# StreamSets Data Collector : Address already in use

Tags: streamsets

First of all, I am new to Streamsets.

I installed the Full Tarball tar, following the instructions for Systemd systems, since I'm working on a Ubuntu 16.04 VM (host is Windows 10).

It worked well for a time, but when i restarted my VM, SDC stopeds working. I deleted my VM and tried with a new one, and I now have the following error when starting the sdc service :

```
 Job for sdc.socket failed. See "systemctl status sdc.socket" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

When I look at the first option, I have this error message :

```
sdc.socket : Failed to listen on sockets : Address already in use
Failed to listen on sdc.socket
```

I let the default configuration during the installation, so the listening port is 18630.
When I look at the running process to see which one uses this port, there's none (`lof -i :18630 | grep LISTEN`). Same on host.

Does anyone have an idea about this ?

Comment: You might need `sudo` for the `lsof` and also `-n` option to prevent name mapping.  Is there any output of `sudo lsof -n -i :18630` ?

Comment: @JeffEvans Thank you for your comment. When I execute your command, I actually have 3 results, which weren't there with my command. This way, I can kill the process using my port, and restart my service.